# Is there any way to set the default data source for the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, import

When I launch the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard for SQL Server 2014, the selection in the **Data source** drop-down defaults to **.Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC**.  This happens regardless of whether I launch the wizard standalone, or from the context menu after right-clicking on a database within the SSMS Object Explorer.

Is there a way, perhaps through a registry setting, to change that default value to a data source I will use regularly, such as SQL Server Native Client or the Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server?

Comment: I thought that was driven by whether you select Import Data or Export Data from the SSMS context window but SSMS 2014 at least is proving me a liar. I could have sworn that an earlier version (2005/2008) at least would set the context for the first or second screen based on whether you were importing or exporting into the given catalog.

Comment: That's my recollection, as well.  Perhaps it was just an oversight during 2014 development?